# How to analyze and fix heap dump problems for hazelcast in WSO2 API Manager 1.10?

Tags: wso2, hazelcast, wso2-api-manager

We have a problem with our setup of WSO2 API Manager 1.10.0. We're using a clustered setup, with 3 gateway-worker-nodes and a manager node; separate store, publisher & key manager nodes (We recently updated from v1.8.0 to 1.10.0).

After the upgrade, every ~2 weeks, all our worker-nodes (and sometimes other nodes) heapdumps and crashes (pretty much at the same time).

Analyzing the heap dumps reveal:

```
28,509 instances of "com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.WriteHandler", loaded by "hazelcast" occupy 945,814,400 (44.42%) bytes

28,509 instances of "com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.ReadHandler", loaded by "hazelcast" occupy 940,796,960 (44.18%) bytes
```

with thread:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.iobalancer.IOBalancerThread @ 0x7877eb628 hz.wso2.pubstore.domain.instance.IOBalancerThread Thread
```

We've not been able to search for a remedy. The logs tells us nothing other than the nodes getting OOM Exception. This happens on nodes with very little traffic and on nodes with very high traffic (different environments have the same behavior).

Anyone come across a similar behavior? Any ideas for going forward?

Comment: What is the underlying Hazelcast version?

Comment: Hazelcast version 3.5.2

Comment: There's a memory leak which was recently fixed (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/7648). You should update the Hazelcast version to at least 3.6.2, better newer. I hope this helps.

Comment: We have similar issue on WSO2 API-M. But how can I upgrade Hazelcast to 3.6.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This did indeed turn out to be a memory-leak issue with Hazelcast. After upgrading to a later version, this problem stopped.

In order to upgrade Hazelcast, there's a bit of "trickery" to be done.

1) Download the WSO2 GitHub repo (or simply the pom-file) for your specific Hazelcast version here: https://github.com/wso2/orbit/tree/master/hazelcast

2) Change the Hazelcast version in this section of the POM (to your preferred version):

```
<properties>
    <version.hazelcast>3.7.2</version.hazelcast>
</properties>
```

3) Build the package.

4) Deploy the built package as a Patch to your server.

This is a "work-around" as it's only possible to patch components with the same name as the ones already shipping with the product.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However, can you provide more details about how to "Deploy the built package as a Patch"?

Comment: In <WSO2_HOME>/repository/components/patches create a new patch directory (with an incremental number, for e.g. patch0100 and then drop the jar-file in there). When you restart the server, you'll see it patching the file(s) you put in the patch-folder. Also see: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM1100/WSO2+Patch+Application+Process